# How do I post JavaScript added input values in Razor? (No MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I'm working on a Razor Page web application (no MVC) and currently trying to create a page where an admin (basicly an user) can create an Exam with certain inputs and questions.

However the questions section is dynamic. There are 3 question types and the user must select an option and press the button 'Add Question' before the inputs are shown (because each question type has different inputs). The user can add as many questions to the exam as he/she likes.
[Question inputs example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkQ9N.png)

My Exam class

```
public class Exam
    {
        public Exam()
        {
            this.Id = 0;
            this.Name = "";
            this.Users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
            this.Record = new List<Record>();
            this.CreatedByUserId = "";
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public List<Record> Record { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    }
```

My Razor page

```
@page
@using iD_Develops.Models
@model iD_Develops.Pages.Examination.MyExams.CreateModel

<div class="container-md">
    <h2>Creating new exam</h2>
    <p><span class="text-danger">*</span> is a required field</p>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="text">
            <label for="floatingInput">Exam name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <div class="form-floating">
            <select class="form-select" id="floatingSelect">
                <option selected>-</option>
                <option value="1">English course - Beginner</option>
                <option value="2">English course - Intermediate</option>
                <option value="3">English course - Advanced</option>
                <option value="4">Dutch course - Beginner</option>
                <option value="5">Dutch course - Intermediate</option>
                <option value="6">Dutch course - Advanced</option>
            </select>
            <label for="floatingSelect">Add to course</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <div class="input-group" style="max-width: 300px;">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" style="min-width: 130px;" placeholder="Exam time length" min="0" aria-label="Exam time length" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">minutes</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Leave blank or fill 0 for no time length.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="text">
            <label for="floatingInput">Rules<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Settings</h4>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
            Enable summary after submitting exam
        </label>
    </div>
    <h4>Questions</h4>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3" id="empty-exam">
        <p>There are currently no questions...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3" id="add-question-btn">
        <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 300px;">
            <select class="form-select" style="min-width: 130px;" id="inputQuestionSelect">
                <option selected value="openquestion">Open question</option>
                <option value="multiplechoice">Multiple choice</option>
                <option value="trueorfalse">True or false</option>
            </select>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" onclick="javascript:addQuestion()">Add question</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-page="/Examination/MyExams/Index" role="button">Save</a>
</div>
```

In the div where **id="add-question-btn"** I call a JavaScript function that adds inputs according to the selected value of the .

Part of my js code:

```
var questionCount = 0;
function addQuestion() {
    var emptyQuestions = document.getElementById('empty-exam');
    if (emptyQuestions.style.display != 'none') {
        emptyQuestions.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var select = document.getElementById('inputQuestionSelect');
    var questionType = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    switch (questionType) {
        case 'openquestion':
            addOpenQuestion();
            break;
        case 'multiplechoice':
            addMultipleChoiceQuestion();
            break;
        case 'trueorfalse':
            addTrueOrFalseQuestion();
            break;
    }
}

function addOpenQuestion() {
    var addQuestionBtn = document.getElementById('add-question-btn');
    var parentDiv = addQuestionBtn.parentNode;

    if (addQuestionBtn) {
        var questionNumber = document.createElement('h3');
        questionNumber.innerHTML = 'Question ' + (questionCount + 1);

        //Scenario input
        var colScenarioDiv = document.createElement('div');
        colScenarioDiv.className = 'col-md-6 mb-3';
        var scenarioInputDiv = createInputsDiv("Scenario text", true);

        //Question input
        var colQuestionTextDiv = document.createElement('div');
        colQuestionTextDiv.className = 'col-md-6 mb-3';
        var questionInputDiv = createInputsDiv("Question text", true);

        //Answer input
        var colAnswerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        colAnswerDiv.className = 'col-md-6 mb-3';
        var answerInputDiv = createInputsDiv("Correct answer", false);

        //Points input
        var colPointsDiv = document.createElement('div');
        colPointsDiv.className = 'col-md-6 mb-3';
        var pointsDiv = createPointsDiv();

        // Error check
        if (questionNumber && colScenarioDiv && colQuestionTextDiv && colAnswerDiv && colPointsDiv)    {
            parentDiv.insertBefore(questionNumber, addQuestionBtn);

            colScenarioDiv.appendChild(scenarioInputDiv);
            parentDiv.insertBefore(colScenarioDiv, addQuestionBtn);

            colQuestionTextDiv.appendChild(questionInputDiv);
            parentDiv.insertBefore(colQuestionTextDiv, addQuestionBtn);

            colAnswerDiv.appendChild(answerInputDiv);
            parentDiv.insertBefore(colAnswerDiv, addQuestionBtn);

            colPointsDiv.appendChild(pointsDiv);
            parentDiv.insertBefore(colPointsDiv, addQuestionBtn);

            questionCount++;
        }
    }
}
function createInputsDiv(inputText, required) {
    var divElement = document.createElement('div');
    divElement.className = "form-floating";

    var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputElement.type = 'text';
    inputElement.className = 'form-control';
    inputElement.id = 'floatingInput';
    inputElement.placeholder = 'text';

    var labelElement = document.createElement('label');
    labelElement.htmlFor = 'floatingInput';
    if (required) {
        ;
        labelElement.innerHTML = inputText;

        var spanElement = document.createElement('span');
        spanElement.className = 'text-danger';
        spanElement.innerHTML = '*'

        $(spanElement).appendTo(labelElement);
    }
    else {
        labelElement.innerHTML = inputText;
    }

    if (divElement && inputElement && labelElement) {
        divElement.appendChild(inputElement);
        divElement.appendChild(labelElement);
    }
    return divElement;
}
```

My struggle here is to 'Post' these dynamically added inputs from JavaScript to my OnPost() function in the PageModel class because I can't figure out how to send them as parameters.

Ultimately, I'd like to post ALL of the inputs (including the exam inputs such as exam name, etc) together to the database upon pressing the Save button.

I've tried to use the exam model in a foreach loop with a switch case and work with updating the model so I didn't need to use JavaScript.
**HTML**

```
<h4>Questions</h4>
    @if (Model.NewExam.Questions.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var q in Model.NewExam.Questions)
        {
            switch (q)
            {
                case OpenQuestion o:
                    //Show inputs here for open question
                    break;
                case MultipleChoiceQuestion m:
                    //Show inputs here for multiple choice
                    break;
                case TrueOrFalseQuestion t:
                    //Show inputs here for true or false
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3" id="empty-exam">
            <p>There are currently no questions...</p>
        </div>
    }
```

**PageModel**

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Exam NewExam { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string QuestionTypeOption { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            NewExam = new Exam
            {
                Id = 25,
                Questions = new List<Question>()
            };
        }
        public IActionResult OnPostAddQuestion()
        {
            switch (QuestionTypeOption)
            {
                case "openquestion":
                    NewExam.Questions.Add(new OpenQuestion());
                    break;
                case "multiplechoice":
                    NewExam.Questions.Add(new MultipleChoiceQuestion());
                    break;
                case "trueorfalse":
                    NewExam.Questions.Add(new TrueOrFalseQuestion());
                    break;
            }
            return RedirectToPage("Create", this.NewExam);
        }
    }
```

When I click the Add question button it executes the OnPostAddQuestion() in the PageModel.
However the 'NewExam' empties as going through the OnPost function and giving me *object reference not set to an instance of an object error* because a new instance of the PageModel class is created upon each request.
I could've worked this out by saving this to the database but I think executing a database query after adding each question (which isn't definitive) is requiring a lot of resources.

Comment: Can you share the code about calling `OnPostAddQuestion`?You need to pass the value of `NewExam` when calling `OnPostAddQuestion`.

Comment: Yes, it's the last code block. Do you mean I have to pass the NewExam as parameter for OnPostAddQuestion()?

Comment: Yes,If not,you will not get the NewExam in your `OnPostAddQuestion`.

Comment: The only thing i can find about passing an object as parameter is passing the ID and execute a GET request to the database inside the OnPost handler. Is there any work-around for passing a collection of objects to the handler without using database?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use a form and hidden inputs to pass NewExam to the handler rather than using <a> tag.